# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 8007007e

Tags: .net, windows-services, com-interop, 32-bit

We have developed a project which crawls all the documents of Sharepoint and finds the legal terms and insert into Database. For that, we have created an installer which can work in all environments. It seems to working fine everywhere except in few Win Server machines like Win 2003 (at Customer's locations). We have already compared the configuration with the machines where it's working fine but we are constantly getting the same error as mentioned below:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 8007007e

Please provide the help or pointers.

Comment: You are forgetting to deploy a required DLL.  Find its name with SysInternals' ProcMon utility.